# How to draw minor grid every 0.1 with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example, I have a plot with 0 - 1 for x-axis and y-axis. I want to draw panel.grid.minor every 0.1.

what should I do?

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,.1)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,.1))`

Comment: this would work better: `scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0,1,.1)) + scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0,1,.1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

xy <- data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10))

mybreaks <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = mybreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = mybreaks)
```

[image]